# O que um atributo HTML value deve conter?

Tags: html

Em uma perspectiva de manutenibilidade e organização o que deve conter um atributo value? um número que representa uma palavra:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="order" value="1">Masculino</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="order" value="2">Feminino</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="loja" value="1">Ricardo Eletro</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="loja" value="2">Submarino</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="loja" value="3">Casas Bahia</label>
```

ou o conteúdo pronto para ser inserido/buscado na base de dados por exemplo:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="order" value="Masculino">Masculino</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="order" value="Feminino">Feminino</label>
<option value="MaisCaroPrimeiro">Mais caro Primeiro</option>
<label><input type="radio" name="loja" value="RicardoEletro">Ricardo Eletro</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="loja" value="Submarino">Submarino</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="loja" value="CasasBahia">Casas Bahia</label>
```

Quando e onde deverá ser realizada a conversão para o valor real?

Comment: Cara, baseado em opiniões, ou seja, depende muito do gosto da pessoa. Eu prefiro o código, (1,2,3...) no caso de sexo, pode ser que seja usado (f, m)...

Comment: O que você coloca no `value` é o que será enviado para o servidor. No caso de um *radio button* - onde o usuário final não vê o valor do atributo - o mais simples é colocar o dado que será mais fácil de ser tratado pelo servidor. (lembrando sempre de **validar** o dado antes de usá-lo)

Comment: Editei com mais um exemplo

Comment: Colocar um valor que esteja dentro do escopo do `input` sempre será a melhor abordagem, é muito mais fácil você identificar o que se trata um `select` com valor `m` ou `male` do que um com valor `1`. Você não precisa escrever o valor "completo", mas sim o suficiente pra você não gerar mais complexidade no seu código, mas tudo isso é minha opinião apenas, boas práticas, etc.

Comment: Eu votei para reabrir. Na minha opinião, esta pergunta não poderia ser tratado especificamente como "baseado em opiniões". Se você está declarando que possui um método de "pesquisa" que tem como feature "ordernar registros da maneira que quiser" o mais alto nível seria que você tivesse os values legíveis. O motivo desses values serem legíveis, é que imagine que você fosse disponibilizar seu método sobre um webservices por exemplo, o que é mais legível para sua camada de negocios ? algo que represente seu negócio (ordernar_por_idade_asc) ou por nome de colunas (idade ASC) ?

Comment: @wryel Entendi sua explicação.

Comment: Como estão dizendo, tudo depende da modelagem dos seus dados e do que você faz com eles. Não quer [edit] a pergunta e acrescentar informações sobre essa parte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `value` é a informação que será enviado pro servidor, pode ser usado `1, 2, f, m, masculino, feminino`, tanto faz. Porque é tu que vai receber essa informação e tratar a utilização dela. No W3S eu encontrei [esse exemplo usando input de texto](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_value) que deve esclarecer um pouco sua dúvida.

Mas no fim quando o servidor receber a resposta do botão marcado ele vai receber o valor indicado no atributo `value`, simples assim.

Answer (score 1):

No caso do "radio", o value determina o valor da resposta... Pode ser tanto 1,2 / Masculino, Feminino / M, F. Depende de como você vai tratar isso depois.